# Python program Works perfectly fine on idle, but wont work when i click the program on the desktop

Tags: python

Just like the title, the code works perfectly fine, without any errors at all, and when i tested certain things, modules that didn't need to be installed separately would work, but the ones that needed to be installed through the command terminal will just make the program close automatically.

Does anyone know how to fix this

i tested running the code with specific modules, with a code "input('press enter to exit.')" so i have to close the window manually. Only the modules i had to download separately would make the program close automatically.

this is my code

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import subprocess as rr
from playsound import playsound
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import time
import webbrowser
import os
import random
import operator
import psutil
response = random.randint(1,2)
if response==1:
        re = 'Acheive.mp3'
elif response==2:
        re = 'At-Your-Service.mp3'
def close_app(app_name):
    running_apps=psutil.process_iter(['pid','name']) #returns names of running processes
    found=False
    for app in running_apps:
        sys_app=app.info.get('name').split('.')[0].lower()

        if sys_app in app_name.split() or app_name in sys_app:
            pid=app.info.get('pid') #returns PID of the given app if found running
            
            try: #deleting the app if asked app is running.(It raises error for some windows apps)
                app_pid = psutil.Process(pid)
                app_pid.terminate()
                found=True
            except: pass
            
        else: pass
    if not found:
        print(app_name+" not found running")
    else:
        print(app_name+'('+sys_app+')'+' closed')
def takeCommand():
    
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    playsound(re)
    
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Listening...")
        r.pause_threshold = 1
        audio = r.listen(source)

    try:
        print("Recognizing...")
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language ='en-in')
        print(f"User said: {query}\n")

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print("Unable to Recognize your voice.")
        return "None"
    
    return query
query = takeCommand().lower()

if 'game on' in query or 'steam' in query:
        playsound('Jarvis-Game.mp3')
        rr.Popen("C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steam.exe")
elif "let's chat" in query or "discord" in query:
        keyboard = Controller()
        keyboard.press(Key.ctrl)
        keyboard.press(Key.alt)
        keyboard.press('q')
        keyboard.release(Key.ctrl)
        keyboard.release(Key.alt)
        keyboard.release('q')
elif "tunes" in query or 'spotify' in query:
        keyboard = Controller()
        keyboard.press(Key.ctrl)
        keyboard.press(Key.alt)
        keyboard.press('s')
        keyboard.release(Key.ctrl)
        keyboard.release(Key.alt)
        keyboard.release('s')
        time.sleep(5)
        keyboard.press(Key.space)
        keyboard.release(Key.space)
elif "watch something" in query or 'youtube' in query:
        webbrowser.open("https://www.youtube.com/")
elif "introduce" in query or 'who are you' in query:
        playsound('Jarvis-Intro.mp3')
elif 'model' in query or 'untiy' in query:
        keyboard = Controller()
        keyboard.press(Key.ctrl)
        keyboard.press(Key.alt)
        keyboard.press('u')
        keyboard.release(Key.ctrl)
        keyboard.release(Key.alt)
        keyboard.release('u')
        playsound('Project.mp3')
elif 'shutdown' in query or 'security protocol' in query:
        playsound('Shutting-Down.mp3')
        os.system("rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0,1,0")
elif 'uploaded' in query:
        playsound('Uploaded.mp3')
elif 'music' in query:
        query = takeCommand().lower()
        if 'cyberdream' in query:
                webbrowser.open('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yhCuCqJbOVE')
        elif 'jazz' in query:
                webbrowser.open('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=idlUMwT4w84&t=2993s')
        elif 'upbeat' in query:
                webbrowser.open('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uoSTi_HZj5o&list=RDuoSTi_HZj5o&start_radio=1')
elif 'google' in query:
        query = takeCommand().lower()
        webbrowser.open('https://www.google.com/search?q='+query)
elif 'solve' in query:
        response = random.randint(1,2)
        if response==1:
                re = 'Acheive.mp3'
        elif response==2:
                re = 'At-Your-Service.mp3'
        playsound(re)
        r = sr.Recognizer()
        my_mic_device = sr.Microphone(device_index=1)
        with my_mic_device as source:
                r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
                audio = r.listen(source)
        my_string=r.recognize_google(audio)
        print(my_string)
        def get_operator_fn(op):
            return {
                '+' : operator.add,
                '-' : operator.sub,
                'x' : operator.mul,
                '*' : operator.mul,
                '/' : operator.__truediv__,
                'divided' :operator.__truediv__,
                'Mod' : operator.mod,
                'mod' : operator.mod,
                '^' : operator.xor,
                }[op]
        def eval_binary_expr(op1, oper, op2):
            op1,op2 = int(op1), int(op2)
            return get_operator_fn(oper)(op1, op2)
        print(eval_binary_expr(*(my_string.split())))
        time.sleep(5)
elif 'close' in query and 'app' in query:
        query = takeCommand().lower()
        close_app(query)
elif 'skip' in query and 'video' in query:
        time.sleep(3)
        keyboard = Controller()
        keyboard.press(Key.shift)
        keyboard.press('n')
        keyboard.release(Key.shift)
        keyboard.release('n')
```

before i reset my computer to fix the microphone, it was working perfectly fine and had no troubles.

Comment: IDLE is a special snowflake in how it runs scripts. The behavior of the scripts automatically closing when done is how they normally operate, and that's the behavior you should be designing your programs around.

Comment: If you want your script to keep running at the end, a simple way to do that is to add `input("press Enter to quit...")`, and it will wait infinitely.